# Python Object of type Binary is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, mongodb, port, json-serializable

I'm trying to pull data from the `MongoDB port` of some threads with `MongoClient`. However, I am getting an error when `writing` to the `JSON` file. I think there is a `Binary` data type in the incoming `data`. How do I fix this error?

My code:

```
import json
import pymongo as pymongo


def get_ip_data():
    db_datas = []
    for ip_line in json_data:
        try:
            replace_ip = ip_line.replace("\n", "")
            client = pymongo.MongoClient(replace_ip, 27017)
            client.server_info()

            db_names = client.list_database_names()
            list_collections = client.admin.command({'listCollections': 1.0}, {'authorizedCollections': True})
            host_info = client.admin.command({'hostInfo': 1})
            server_status = client.admin.command({'serverStatus': 1})
            lock_info = client.admin.command({'lockInfo': 1})
            build_info = client.admin.command({'buildInfo': 1})

            db_data = {f"{ip_line}, db_names": db_names, "collections_list": list_collections,
                       "server_status": server_status, "host_info": host_info, "lock_info": lock_info,
                       "build_info": build_info}
            db_datas.append(db_data)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        finally:
            with open("./data.json", "wt") as write_data:
                write_data.write(json.dumps(db_datas, indent=4))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("./ip_list.txt", "r") as json_data:
        json_data = json_data.readlines()

    get_ip_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on what you want to get in the result

The recommended way is to use pymongo's [bson.json_util](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html#bson.json_util.dumps) to correctly dump your dictionary with bson-typed objects to json. In this case, them will be represented as something like that

```
"your_binary_field": {
    "$binary": {
        "base64": "Xi6aRRv9SWAJtTK4ScAoKDrw4cU5bek=",
        "subType": "00"
    }
},
```

Which can be correctly read by the bson package.

Alternatively, you can recursively walk through your `db_datas` items, and cast all the bson.Binary objects to the strings, or other json-serializable values, as expample, using bson.Binary.decode.